# Создавать поток для каждого вызова процедуры

Tags: c#, vb.net, многопоточность, .net

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно для каждого вызова процедуры (**с параметрами!**) создавать поток. Как это можно сделать? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов есть два.

Первый - использовать [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1h2f2459.aspx).

Второй - написать класс и в нем прописать все параметры, которые нужны. При вызове создать экземпляр класса, заполнить параметры и вызывать в новом потоке паблик-метод класса.

Второй подход часто бывает нагляднее.

ПРИМЕР:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationZ
{
    class Thh 
    {

        public string a = "";

        public void b()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Start " + a);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(r.Next(1000,5000));
            Console.WriteLine("Stop " + a);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thh c = new Thh();
                c.a = "Th" + i.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(c.b);
                th.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста , как создавать экземпляр класса в цикле (я аедь не знаю сколько будет вызовов) ?

Comment: 5 мин. Добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Их больше, чем 2 - есть еще [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`][1]и специфичные для `.NET4` [`Parallel.For`][2] и [`TaskFactory.StartNew`.][3]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kbf0f1ct
[2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for
[3]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew

Comment: С 4кой почти не работал, поэтому не пишу.

Насчет пула потоков, я бы его не рекомендовал использовать для начальных задач. Довольно своеобразный инструмент.

Comment: @SilverIce Ну `ThreadPool`-то был всегда и, вообще говоря, является лучшим решением, нежели олдскульное ручное конструирование тредов.

Answer (score 1):

Если пишете под 4 фреймворк, настоятельно рекомендую не связываться с классом Thread. Используйте таски и продолжения (ContinueWith).